# My Asus Windows 10 laptop wont connect to bluetooth devices

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, audio, bluetooth, asus-laptop

My Bluetooth just says "not connected" on my action center. When I try to connect to things it just says can't connect. I've tried updating my drivers, changing the Bluetooth running setting from Manual to Automatic, but nothing will connect. The device I've been trying to connect to is an LG mini Hi-Fi speaker system. It usually works and connect automatically but all of a sudden it has stopped connecting.

Comment: Ensure you have latest drivers installed for wireless comms on your laptop, and that you have the connecting device set to discoverable. Bluetooth troubleshooting is often best resolved by referring to the device's manual but do ensure you have latest drivers - usually obtainable from manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with my HP laptop. Check your laptop's maker for updated drivers.  Then download to a folder on your desktop. Turn off your bluetooth radio then Goto device manager and uninstall your bluetooth, you then have to go to Devices Printers and uninstall this device.  Install the new drivers then add the device.